# how to define a 'co-participate' property in OWL or RDFS?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I'd like to know how to express the concept that: if 2 agents are participants in one event, they should be linked with a symmetric property 'co-participate'.

I feel I could make some restrictions but don't know how.

The event ontology is defined here: http://motools.sourceforge.net/event/event.html

Comment: Can you add the OWL version and/or OWL2 profile you want/can use? Note that you can use SWRL to solve your problem.

Comment: @dhke, thank you.  I'm using http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#.  Good to know SWRL.  But is there a more primitive way to do it? I suppose it rather common need.

Comment: The XML namespace is the same for both OWL and OWL2 so that does not tell you anything.

Comment: @dhke You don't need SWRL to do this;  this can be done using OWL2's property chains.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Which is why I was asking for which language level was available.

Comment: @dhke Ah, good point.  Since [OWL1 ontologies are valid OWL 2 ontologies](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/#Relationship_to_OWL_1), and most tools/reasoners/etc. support OWL2, I generally assume that people are using OWL2 unless they specifically mention otherwise.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Don't forget, that OWL2 has language profiles. And Uli Sattler's reasoner list (http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/reasoners.html, which is nowadays far from complete) has quite a few that only can do a subset. Anyway your answer is correct :-)

Comment: @dhke And it will work even when there aren't named individuals that could trigger a SWRL rule.  E.g., if we say that `{a} subClassOf (sponsored some (Event and (inverse(participatesIn) value x) and (inverse(participatesIn) value y)))`, (i.e., that A sponsored some Event that x and y participated in), we can still infer that x and y coparticipated with each other, even though the event individual isn't named.  That's the big drawback of SWRL rules, in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73693/discussion-between-dhke-and-joshua-taylor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *if 2 agents are participants in one event, they should be linked with
>   a symmetric property 'co-participate'.*

You can do this in OWL2 by using a sub-property chain axiom.  Since the data looks like:

[image]

we can see that there is a chain from X to Y with the form

participatesIn • participatesIn<sup>-1</sup>

So, you can assert that:

(participatesIn • participatesIn<sup>-1</sup>) ⊑ coParticipatesWith

and then you'll be able to infer that

X coParticipatesWith Y
    Y coParticipatesWith X

In Protege it looks like this:

[image: protege screenshot]

Here's an OWL ontology that contains the axiom:

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:       a       owl:Ontology .

:participatesIn  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

:coParticipatesWith  a          owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( :participatesIn _:b0 ) .
_:b0    owl:inverseOf  :participatesIn .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/participatesIn"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/coParticipatesWith">
    <owl:propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/participatesIn"/>
      <rdf:Description>
        <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238387/1281433/participatesIn"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </owl:propertyChainAxiom>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Good to know I can achieve it and still stay within OWL. Thank you @Joshua, I'm impressed and grateful.