# How to express 2 events are related if they have at least one common participant in OWL or RDFS

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I'd like to define a symmetric property to express that: if 2 events are related if they have at least one common participant.

The event ontology is defined here: http://motools.sourceforge.net/event/event.html

This inverse question is: [how to define a 'co-participate' property in OWL or RDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238387/how-to-define-a-co-participate-property-in-owl-or-rdfs)

It'd be great if someone can elaborate the 2 sides of the coin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a property relatedTo that relates events, then you can use another property chain axiom (DL and Manchester syntax):

participatesIn<sup>-1</sup> • participatesIn ⊑ relatedTo
    **inverse**(participatesIn) **o** participatesIn **SubPropertyOf** relatedTo

Then, with data like

E1 ←<sub>participatesIn</sub> X →<sub>participatesIn</sub> E2

you can infer that:

E1 relatedTo E2

Comment: thank you again. After 2 hours reading I can understand your syntax. It's more than I expected.

Comment: You can also infer that `E1 relatedTo E1 and `E2 relatedTo E2`. Depending on what you want, it may be alright, or not.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Thanks for the correction (subclassof v. subpropertyof).